# Photoshop's "Actual Pixels" display wrong

Tags: adobe-photoshop

In 12 years of using Photoshop I've never seen an issue like this.

I have a picture. When I choose Vɪᴇᴡ ▶ Aᴄᴛᴜᴀʟ Pɪxᴇʟs the image is displaying incorrectly on my monitor. On the left is what my image looks like (zoomed up by a factor of 4 using nearest-neighbor). On the right is a screenshot of what it looks like when displayed at "Actual Size" (also zoomed up).

[image: Actual result shows some blurred pixels]

What setting could possibly be causing this?

<sub>*Photoshop CS4 on Windows 7x64, on a machine with multiple graphics cards by NVIDIA.*</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it! I had recently used the NVIDIA Control Panel to force FXAA on for every application. Apparently this anti-aliasing was being applied to the images 'rendered' by Photoshop.

Using the Control Panel to exempt Photoshop from this (and all anti-aliasing, for safety) fixed the problem after a restart of the app.